# Why anbox is not found on the Application Finder of Ubuntu 20.04 with XFCE4?

Tags: ubuntu, android, snap

My goal is to install anbox in Ubuntu 20.04 and run it through PuTTy (with X11 Forwarding, can it be done?) or Widnows Remote Desktop Connection.

My actual result: Installation successful. However I can't find anbox using the application finder.

My expected result: I can find anbox using the application finder.

What I did

```
sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```

Output of `snap list`

```
root@ubuntu-1cpu-1gb-sg-sin1:~# snap list
Name   Version    Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
anbox  4-56c25f1  186    latest/beta    morphis     devmode
core   16-2.50.1  11167  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
```

Comment: Try to update `anbox` through: `snap refresh --edge --devmode anbox`

Comment: I run it manually `sudo anbox session-manager` it throws `segmentation fault` and then I updated it to the `latest/edge` then run the command again, it throws `no video device`.